# Router link in angular 6 using query parameters

Tags: angular, router

I have router link that navigate between pages and I send parameters in url using

```
queryParamsHandling: "merge"
```

In some situations I want to remove specific parameter from url but I don't want to  loose all parameters.

My url look like:
http://localhost:4200/school/440404?SelectedTab=1&UserName=bat7

After route I want to remove SelectedTab parameter bun not UserName Parameter.

the URL shold look like:

http://localhost:4200/school/440404?UserName=bat7

the router code is in different component,

that contains a back button that do the route, using the code behind:

```
this.router.navigate([], { relativeTo: this.route, queryParamsHandling: "preserve" });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> Angular allowed two type navigation strategy one is absolute path and
>   second is relative path.

1. Using absolute path strategy we need to write hard code path on components level.
2. Using relative path strategy we need to write path only route-level.

For the solution of question please follow below steps.

**Steps 1:** Declare routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/school', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'school', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'school/:SelectedTab/:UserName', component: SchoolComponent },
];
```

**Step 2:** Declare method for go to school in your first component like below. Then You get similar url like

e.g. `http://localhost:4200/school/1/sa`

```
goToSchool() {
    let object: any = {};
    object.SelectedTab = 1;
    object.UserName = 'sa';
    this.router.navigate([object.SelectedTab, object.UserName], { relativeTo: this.route});
  }
```

**Step 3:** After then go back from school you need to modify url like below code for getting only `UserName`

```
 GoBackFromSchool() {
    this.router.navigate(['../../'], { relativeTo: this.route, queryParams: { UserName: 'sa' } });
  }
```

e.g. : `http://localhost:4200/school?UserName=sa`

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, but my problem is that the parameters are dynamically added from difference components and when I navigate I don't want to create them again.